# Is it an MD5 digest in this Python script?

Tags: python, md5, digest, hashlib

I am trying to understand this simple hashlib code in Python that has been given to me the other day on Stackoverflow:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("Nobody inspects")
m.update(" the spammish repetition here")
m.digest()
'\xbbd\x9c\x83\xdd\x1e\xa5\xc9\xd9\xde\xc9\xa1\x8d\xf0\xff\xe9'
m.digest_size
16
m.block_size
64
print m
```

I thought that `print m` would show me the MD5 digest of the phrase: "Nobody inspects the spammish repetition here", but as a result I got this line on my local host:

```
<md5 HASH object @ 01806220>
```

Strange, when I refreshed the page, I got another line:

```
<md5 HASH object @ 018062E0>
```

and every time when I refresh it, I get another value:

> md5 HASH object @ 017F8AE0
>
> md5 HASH object @ 01806220
>
> md5 HASH object @ 01806360
>
> md5 HASH object @ 01806400
>
> md5 HASH object @ 01806220

Why is it so? I guess, what I have in each line flowing "@" is not really a digest. Then, what is it? And how can I display MD5 digest here in this code?

My python version is Python 2.5 and the framework I am currently using is webapp (I have downloaded it together with SDK from "Google App Engine")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hashlib.hash` object doesn't implement its own `__str__`, so the default to-string operation is used, which prints the class name followed by its `id` (address).

(Use [`.hexdigest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) to get the hex MD5 string.)

Comment: @ KennyTM: Thank You, Kenny. Can You, please, tell me what is an "object's own __str__"?

Comment: @brilliant: The `x.__str__()` is equivalent to `str(x)`.

Comment: to be more precise, `x.__str__()` is what `str(x)` will call to get its result.  This stuff is all well covered in the docs: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__

Answer (score 3):

```
print m.hexdigest()
```

UPADATE: `hexdigest()` gives another representation of `digest()`. Every character in digest is transformed into its hex representation. You can transform it with the following function:

```
def digest_to_hex(chars):  
  res = ''  
  for c in chars:  
    res = res + '%02x' % ord(c)  
  return res
```

You can also use the generator expresion

```
''.join('%02x' % ord(x) for x in m.digest())
```

or

```
m.digest().encode('hex')
```

BTW: You can use `dir(some_object)` to get a list of its elements, and `help(some_object)` (in the interactive interpreter) to get more informations about it.

Comment: @ Rudi: Rudi, thank You very much!!! Can you, please, tell me what's the difference between digest and hexdigest?

Comment: hexdigest() gives another representation of digist(). Every character in digest is transformed into it's hex representation.

You can transform it with the following function:


`def digest_to_hex(chars):
  res = ''
  for c in chars:
    res = res + '%02x' % ord(c)
  return res`

You can also use the generator expresion
''.join(['%02x' % ord(x) for x in m.digest()])

Comment: I repost the comment as new awnser, because I can't get the code to be correct displayed in a comment.